# Doppler shift equivalent for a short nonsinusoidal pulse

Tags: doppler-effect

All of my search results explain Doppler shift in the frequency domain. None explain what happens for a moving source or observer when the transmission is a short unmodulated 'time domain' pulse.  I would guess that each of the spectral components could be Doppler shifted individually, but I would like to have a time-space domain explanation. I would also expect that the Doppler shift equivalent would be a dilation along the spatial axis, but have not seen that discussed.

**My question is:**
*What is the Doppler shift equivalent for a short nonsinusoidal pulse, for example a Gaussian pulse or a hypothetical rectangular pulse?*

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what specifically you're unsure about? Why is 'dilation along the spatial axis' unsatisfactory? What do you mean by a 'time-space domain' explanation?

Comment: Re "Why is 'dilation along the spatial axis' unsatisfactory?"  It would be satisfactory, but I would like to see the derivation without referring to frequency.  That is what I mean by time-space domain (vs frequency domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point target moving with range rate (radial speed) $v_0<<c$ the echo $r(t)$ of the signal $s(t)$ arrives at the emitter with a range delay $\tau (t) = \tau_0 - \alpha t$ assuming that the echo is reflected from the target when the latter is at $R_0-vt$ at instant $t$. Here $\tau_0 = 2R_0/c$ and $\alpha = \frac {2v_0}{c-v_0}\approx \frac{2v_0}{c}$.

Thus the received signal, aside from an irrelevant amplitude factor, is $$r(t)=s(t-\tau(t)) = s(t+\alpha t -\tau_0),$$ and the *time variable* $t$ is just scaled by a factor $1+\alpha$. This scaling is of course consistent with the frequency domain view according to which the frequency component at $f$ becomes $f/(1+\alpha)\approx (1-\alpha)f $, that is shifted by $\alpha f$, and if the bandwidth is narrow then the whole spectrum is shifted by $\alpha f'$ where $f'\approx f_c$ the carrier frequency.

Comment: How would this change if the 'target' was the moving emitter, ie no target reflection--a one way problem--and the signal was observed at a fixed point (the 'receiver')?

Comment: what i described was a two-way radar situation; in comms just drop the factor of 2 in front of  $R_0$, ie, set $\alpha \approx v_0/c$

Comment: If c is the speed of sound and $v_0$ = c what happens to  $\frac {2v_0}{c-v_0}$?

Comment: one way $\alpha = \frac {v_0}{c-v_0}$